# white papers for sharepoint content types?

Tags: sharepoint

we create a lot of custom content types in sharepoint 2010 and have some unknown behavior.
Sometimes we delete a content type, but we can't create a new one with the same display name. We only use the sharepoint gui to create the content types (no visual studio etc).

Is there a white paper for handling sharepoint content types? Which modifications of existing content types are supported by microsoft?

thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

please google you will get number of white paper on the same providing you few links of articles and white paper

http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/04/20/sharepoint-content-structure-let-a-thousand-content-types-bloom/

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=5DDA96C8-3744-48C4-9BDA-C271929FD4AA&displaylang=en

http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/sharepoint-content-types-why-should-i-care

http://www.myriadtech.com.au/blog/Alana/White%20Papers/Planning%20Content%20Types%20in%20SharePoint.pdf